# How do I suppress "unused in wild import" warning in pydev?

Tags: python, pydev

How do I suppress "unused in wild import" warning in pydev?

Comment: What "In the question" means?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Suppressing warning message for import / wild import

```
from django.db import connection #@UnusedImport
from django.db import * #@UnusedWildImport
```

Comment: +1: Just might want to mention that it comes immediately following the import statement to be clear. `from foo import * #@UnusedWildImport`

Comment: Apparently that works for `from x import *` but not `from x import y`. I don't see why PyDev inaccurately displays this warning so often anyway. I get this warning in PyDev for >90% of my imports even when they are clearly being used (and are used without problems). Having that little yellow warning symbol there for this false-warning also makes actual problems harder to detect.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Just *"fakely" use something from that import*:

```
from django.db import connection
_ = connection
```

---

For more details:

Similarly for wildcard:

```
from django.db import *
_ = connection # or anything in the django.db package
```

Personally I often use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
_ = (plt,np,pd,tf)
```

P.S. The other answer does not work for me in PyCharm/Intellij Idea...