# "Unused wild import": Why?

Tags: python, warnings, pydev, python-import

Whenever I import from another module using an asterisk (`from <anymodule> import *`) I am fined with an *"Unused wild import"*-warning. It appears as if this is not the right way to do the import, but why does that syntax exist if we shouldn't be using it?

Comment: I refer you to [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215516/how-do-i-suppress-unused-in-wild-import-warning-in-pydev) to get a solution. The error should be arisen because you're not using a structure you imported: try invoking some of the names imported by the asterisk and it should be removed.

Comment: Syntax exists for some simple cases. I would say that always use of named import is better for all reasons, because with a wild import you can foll into diffucult to debug errors. Books about Python light this question out.

Comment: For projects involving many modules, it may be good practice to use regular imports, or `from module import function`, as it will be clear (for you and others) which module is used for which function. Consider for example the case where two (third party) modules contain functions with the same name..

Comment: Wild imports are useful when you create an interface withing a given package from which the letter defined .py modules should be imported by your interface.

A way for suppressing warning message for wild imports can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215516/how-do-i-suppress-unused-in-wild-import-warning-in-pydev)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That message just tells you that you are importing features from a module that you don't need, which means you should probably import just what you need. You shuld simply use `from foobar import x, y` where `x` and `y` are the elements you actually need.

The syntax `from foobar import *` is more useful in the command-line interpreter when you don't want to think or type many more characters for little benefit. But in a real project, you should not use that syntax since if you use it, it will not be clear which feature from the module you are going to use.